# Mac M1 Android Emulator Screen Record Using ADB Error

Tags: android-emulator, adb, apple-m1, screen-recording

I can't start a screen record command using ADB on Mac M1 using Pixel3 virtual device and Android-28 Arm system image.

Here is some command that I use and the log:

start emulator: `emulator -no-boot-anim -wipe-data -no-snapshot-save -memory 2048 -partition-size 3072 -avd  "Pixel3-28"`

```
ERROR   | bad color buffer handle 0
ERROR   | bad color buffer handle 0
```

start screen record: `adb -P 5037 -s emulator-5554 shell screenrecord --time-limit 10 /sdcard/f8713900.mp4 --verbose`

```
Main display is 1080x2160 @60.00fps (orientation=0)
Configuring recorder for 1080x2160 video/avc at 20.00Mbps
Content area is 1080x2160 at offset x=0 y=0
Stopping encoder and muxer
Encoder failed (err=-38)
```

Here is the log captured from `adb logcat`

```
--------- beginning of main
05-31 15:01:49.486  3135  3362 E SurfaceFlinger: ro.sf.lcd_density must be defined as a build property
05-31 15:01:49.489  3135  3135 W Binder:3135_5: type=1400 audit(0.0:74): avc: denied { call } for scontext=u:r:surfaceflinger:s0 tcontext=u:r:mediacodec:s0 tclass=binder permissive=0 b/77924251
05-31 15:01:49.492  6800  6805 D CCodec  : allocate(c2.android.avc.encoder)
05-31 15:01:49.492  6800  6805 E cutils-trace: Error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
05-31 15:01:49.492  6800  6805 I CCodec  : setting up 'default' as default (vendor) store
05-31 15:01:49.493  6791  6791 V C2Store : in init
05-31 15:01:49.493  6791  6791 V C2Store : loading dll
05-31 15:01:49.494  6800  6805 I CCodec  : Created component [c2.android.avc.encoder]
05-31 15:01:49.494  6800  6805 D CCodecConfig: Query domain & kind failed => BAD_INDEX
05-31 15:01:49.494  6800  6805 D CCodecConfig: read media type: video/raw
05-31 15:01:49.494  6800  6805 D CCodecConfig: read media type: video/avc
05-31 15:01:49.496  6800  6805 I CCodecConfig: query failed after returning 9 values (BAD_INDEX)
05-31 15:01:49.496  6800  6805 D CCodecConfig: c2 config is Dict {
05-31 15:01:49.496  6800  6805 D CCodecConfig:   c2::u32 coded.bitrate.value = 64000
05-31 15:01:49.496  6800  6805 D CCodecConfig:   c2::float coded.frame-rate.value = 30
05-31 15:01:49.496  6800  6805 D CCodecConfig:   c2::u32 coded.pl.level = 20492
05-31 15:01:49.496  6800  6805 D CCodecConfig:   c2::u32 coded.pl.profile = 20481
05-31 15:01:49.496  6800  6805 D CCodecConfig:   c2::u32 coding.intra-refresh.mode = 0
05-31 15:01:49.496  6800  6805 D CCodecConfig:   c2::float coding.intra-refresh.period = 0
05-31 15:01:49.496  6800  6805 D CCodecConfig:   c2::u32 coding.request-sync-frame.value = 0
05-31 15:01:49.496  6800  6805 D CCodecConfig:   c2::i64 coding.sync-frame-interval.value = 1000000
05-31 15:01:49.496  6800  6805 D CCodecConfig:   string input.media-type.value = "video/raw"
05-31 15:01:49.496  6800  6805 D CCodecConfig:   string output.media-type.value = "video/avc"
05-31 15:01:49.496  6800  6805 D CCodecConfig:   c2::u32 raw.color.matrix = 0
05-31 15:01:49.496  6800  6805 D CCodecConfig:   c2::u32 raw.color.primaries = 0
05-31 15:01:49.496  6800  6805 D CCodecConfig:   c2::u32 raw.color.range = 0
05-31 15:01:49.496  6800  6805 D CCodecConfig:   c2::u32 raw.color.transfer = 0
05-31 15:01:49.496  6800  6805 D CCodecConfig:   c2::u32 raw.size.height = 240
05-31 15:01:49.496  6800  6805 D CCodecConfig:   c2::u32 raw.size.width = 320
05-31 15:01:49.496  6800  6805 D CCodecConfig: }
05-31 15:01:49.496  6800  6805 W ColorUtils: expected specified color aspects (0:0:0:0)
05-31 15:01:49.496  6800  6805 D CCodecConfig: no c2 equivalents for color-format
05-31 15:01:49.496  6800  6805 D CCodecConfig: no c2 equivalents for encoder
05-31 15:01:49.496  6791  6791 D C2SoftAvcEnc: Given level 500c does not cover current configuration: adjusting to 500e
05-31 15:01:49.496  6800  6805 D CCodecConfig: c2 config is Dict {
05-31 15:01:49.496  6800  6805 D CCodecConfig:   c2::u32 coded.bitrate.value = 20000000
05-31 15:01:49.496  6800  6805 D CCodecConfig:   c2::float coded.frame-rate.value = 60
05-31 15:01:49.496  6800  6805 D CCodecConfig:   c2::u32 coded.pl.level = 20492
05-31 15:01:49.496  6800  6805 D CCodecConfig:   c2::u32 coded.pl.profile = 20481
05-31 15:01:49.496  6800  6805 D CCodecConfig:   c2::u32 coding.intra-refresh.mode = 0
05-31 15:01:49.496  6800  6805 D CCodecConfig:   c2::float coding.intra-refresh.period = 0
05-31 15:01:49.496  6800  6805 D CCodecConfig:   c2::u32 coding.request-sync-frame.value = 0
05-31 15:01:49.496  6800  6805 D CCodecConfig:   c2::i64 coding.sync-frame-interval.value = 10000000
05-31 15:01:49.496  6800  6805 D CCodecConfig:   string input.media-type.value = "video/raw"
05-31 15:01:49.496  6800  6805 D CCodecConfig:   string output.media-type.value = "video/avc"
05-31 15:01:49.496  6800  6805 D CCodecConfig:   c2::u32 raw.color.matrix = 0
05-31 15:01:49.496  6800  6805 D CCodecConfig:   c2::u32 raw.color.primaries = 0
05-31 15:01:49.496  6800  6805 D CCodecConfig:   c2::u32 raw.color.range = 0
05-31 15:01:49.496  6800  6805 D CCodecConfig:   c2::u32 raw.color.transfer = 0
05-31 15:01:49.496  6800  6805 D CCodecConfig:   c2::u32 raw.size.height = 2160
05-31 15:01:49.496  6800  6805 D CCodecConfig:   c2::u32 raw.size.width = 1080
05-31 15:01:49.496  6800  6805 D CCodecConfig: }
05-31 15:01:49.496  6800  6805 W ColorUtils: expected specified color aspects (0:0:0:0)
05-31 15:01:49.497  6800  6805 D CCodec  : setup formats input: AMessage(what = 0x00000000) = {
05-31 15:01:49.497  6800  6805 D CCodec  :   int32_t frame-rate = 60
05-31 15:01:49.497  6800  6805 D CCodec  :   int32_t height = 2160
05-31 15:01:49.497  6800  6805 D CCodec  :   int64_t i-frame-interval = 10000000
05-31 15:01:49.497  6800  6805 D CCodec  :   int32_t intra-refresh-period = 0
05-31 15:01:49.497  6800  6805 D CCodec  :   string mime = "video/raw"
05-31 15:01:49.497  6800  6805 D CCodec  :   int32_t width = 1080
05-31 15:01:49.497  6800  6805 D CCodec  :   Rect crop(0, 0, 1079, 2159)
05-31 15:01:49.497  6800  6805 D CCodec  :   int32_t android._dataspace = 0
05-31 15:01:49.497  6800  6805 D CCodec  :   int32_t using-sw-read-often = 1
05-31 15:01:49.497  6800  6805 D CCodec  :   int32_t color-format = 2130708361
05-31 15:01:49.497  6800  6805 D CCodec  : } and output: AMessage(what = 0x00000000) = {
05-31 15:01:49.497  6800  6805 D CCodec  :   int32_t bitrate = 20000000
05-31 15:01:49.497  6800  6805 D CCodec  :   Rect crop(0, 0, 1079, 2159)
05-31 15:01:49.497  6800  6805 D CCodec  :   int32_t color-standard = 0
05-31 15:01:49.497  6800  6805 D CCodec  :   int32_t color-range = 0
05-31 15:01:49.497  6800  6805 D CCodec  :   int32_t color-transfer = 0
05-31 15:01:49.497  6800  6805 D CCodec  :   int32_t frame-rate = 60
05-31 15:01:49.497  6800  6805 D CCodec  :   int32_t height = 2160
05-31 15:01:49.497  6800  6805 D CCodec  :   int64_t i-frame-interval = 10000000
05-31 15:01:49.497  6800  6805 D CCodec  :   int32_t intra-refresh-period = 0
05-31 15:01:49.497  6800  6805 D CCodec  :   int32_t level = 4096
05-31 15:01:49.497  6800  6805 D CCodec  :   int32_t max-bitrate = 20000000
05-31 15:01:49.497  6800  6805 D CCodec  :   string mime = "video/avc"
05-31 15:01:49.497  6800  6805 D CCodec  :   int32_t profile = 65536
05-31 15:01:49.497  6800  6805 D CCodec  :   int32_t width = 1080
05-31 15:01:49.497  6800  6805 D CCodec  : }
05-31 15:01:49.497  6800  6805 W Codec2Client: Could not create an input surface from any Codec2.0 services.
05-31 15:01:49.502  6791  6791 E GraphicBufferSource: Unable to set BQ default buffer size to 0x0: -22
05-31 15:01:49.502  6800  6805 D CCodec  : ISConfig start at 0us resume at -1us
05-31 15:01:49.502  6800  6805 D CCodecBufferChannel: [c2.android.avc.encoder#842] Query input allocators returned 0 params => BAD_INDEX (6)
05-31 15:01:49.502  6800  6805 D CCodecBufferChannel: [c2.android.avc.encoder#842] Using basic input block pool with poolID 1 => got 1 - OK (0)
05-31 15:01:49.502  6800  6805 D CCodecBufferChannel: [c2.android.avc.encoder#842] Query input allocators returned 0 params => BAD_INDEX (6)
05-31 15:01:49.503  6800  6805 I CCodecBufferChannel: [c2.android.avc.encoder#842] Created output block pool with allocatorID 16 => poolID 17 - OK
05-31 15:01:49.503  6800  6805 D Codec2Client: config -- call failed. Error code = 6
05-31 15:01:49.503  6800  6805 D CCodecBufferChannel: [c2.android.avc.encoder#842] Configured output block pool ids 17 => OK
05-31 15:01:49.504  3135  3362 E         : HpInterface: Wrong interface type.
05-31 15:01:49.506  3135  3135 E HWComposer: getHdrCapabilities failed for display -1: Invalid display
05-31 15:01:49.506  6791  6808 W GraphicBufferSource: released unpopulated slots: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63]
05-31 15:01:49.508  3022  3072 D gralloc_ranchu: gralloc_alloc: Creating ashmem region of size 4096
05-31 15:01:49.508  6791  6808 D HostConnection: createUnique: call
05-31 15:01:49.508  6791  6808 D HostConnection: HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0x7ee5a18820, tid 6808
05-31 15:01:49.509  6791  6808 D HostConnection: HostComposition ext ANDROID_EMU_CHECKSUM_HELPER_v1 ANDROID_EMU_sync_buffer_data GL_OES_EGL_image_external_essl3 GL_OES_vertex_array_object GL_KHR_texture_compression_astc_ldr ANDROID_EMU_host_side_tracing ANDROID_EMU_gles_max_version_3_0 
05-31 15:01:49.510  6800  6802 D HostConnection: createUnique: call
05-31 15:01:49.510  6800  6802 D HostConnection: HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0x7156a18500, tid 6802
05-31 15:01:49.511  6800  6802 D HostConnection: HostComposition ext ANDROID_EMU_CHECKSUM_HELPER_v1 ANDROID_EMU_sync_buffer_data GL_OES_EGL_image_external_essl3 GL_OES_vertex_array_object GL_KHR_texture_compression_astc_ldr ANDROID_EMU_host_side_tracing ANDROID_EMU_gles_max_version_3_0 
05-31 15:01:49.512  3135  3135 E HWComposer: getSupportedPerFrameMetadata failed for display -1: Invalid display
05-31 15:01:49.515  3135  3135 D EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0x733ca46320: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0x733ca2d620)
05-31 15:01:49.517  6791  6809 D SimpleC2Component: Using output block pool with poolID 0 => got 0 - 0
05-31 15:01:49.517  6791  6809 D C2SoftAvcEnc: Params width 1080 height 2160 level 50 colorFormat 0
05-31 15:01:49.517  3022  3072 D gralloc_ranchu: gralloc_alloc: Creating ashmem region of size 4096
05-31 15:01:49.517  6791  6809 E C2SoftAvcEnc: Unable to set air params = 0x1ad
05-31 15:01:49.517  6791  6809 E gralloc_ranchu: gralloc_lock usage mismatch usage=0x3 cb->usage=0x0
05-31 15:01:49.517  6791  6809 E ion     : ioctl c0044901 failed with code -1: Invalid argument
05-31 15:01:49.518  6791  6809 F Codec2BufferUtils: Codec2BufferUtils.cpp:214] Check failed: (src.width() & 1) == 0 
--------- beginning of crash
05-31 15:01:49.518  6791  6809 F libc    : Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 (SI_TKILL) in tid 6809 (HwBinder:6791_3), pid 6791 (omx@1.0-service)
05-31 15:01:49.518  3135  3135 D EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0x733ca46320: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0x733ca2d620)
05-31 15:01:49.518  3135  3135 D EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0x733ca46320: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0x733ca2d620)
05-31 15:01:49.518  3135  3135 E HWComposer: getLayerReleaseFence failed for display -1: Invalid display
05-31 15:01:49.518  3135  3135 I chatty  : uid=1000(system) /system/bin/surfaceflinger identical 1 line
05-31 15:01:49.518  3135  3135 E HWComposer: getLayerReleaseFence failed for display -1: Invalid display
05-31 15:01:49.521  6812  6812 E cutils-trace: Error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
05-31 15:01:49.523  6813  6813 I crash_dump64: obtaining output fd from tombstoned, type: kDebuggerdTombstone
05-31 15:01:49.523  3158  3158 I /system/bin/tombstoned: received crash request for pid 6809
05-31 15:01:49.523  6813  6813 I crash_dump64: performing dump of process 6791 (target tid = 6809)
05-31 15:01:49.523  6813  6813 F DEBUG   : *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
05-31 15:01:49.523  6813  6813 F DEBUG   : Build fingerprint: 'Android/sdk_gphone_arm64/generic_arm64:9/PSR1.210301.009.B1/7985424:userdebug/dev-keys'
05-31 15:01:49.523  6813  6813 F DEBUG   : Revision: '0'
05-31 15:01:49.523  6813  6813 F DEBUG   : ABI: 'arm64'
05-31 15:01:49.523  6813  6813 F DEBUG   : pid: 6791, tid: 6809, name: HwBinder:6791_3  >>> media.codec <<<
05-31 15:01:49.523  6813  6813 F DEBUG   : signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 (SI_TKILL), fault addr --------
05-31 15:01:49.523  6813  6813 F DEBUG   : Abort message: 'Codec2BufferUtils.cpp:214] Check failed: (src.width() & 1) == 0 '
05-31 15:01:49.523  6813  6813 F DEBUG   :     x0  0000000000000000  x1  0000000000001a99  x2  0000000000000006  x3  0000000000000008
05-31 15:01:49.523  6813  6813 F DEBUG   :     x4  0000000000000000  x5  0000000000000000  x6  0000000000000000  x7  7f7f7f7f7f7fff7f
05-31 15:01:49.523  6813  6813 F DEBUG   :     x8  0000000000000083  x9  1a0650427db1c7c1  x10 0000000000000000  x11 fffffffc7fffffdf
05-31 15:01:49.523  6813  6813 F DEBUG   :     x12 0000000000000001  x13 ffffffffffffffff  x14 ffffffffff000000  x15 ffffffffffffffff
05-31 15:01:49.523  6813  6813 F DEBUG   :     x16 0000007f6882f2c8  x17 0000007f6876d040  x18 0000007ee52d0bb0  x19 0000000000001a87
05-31 15:01:49.523  6813  6813 F DEBUG   :     x20 0000000000001a99  x21 0000007ee52d1468  x22 0000000000000870  x23 0000007ee52d2588
05-31 15:01:49.523  6813  6813 F DEBUG   :     x24 0000007ee52d2588  x25 0000000000000438  x26 0000007ee1239880  x27 0000007ee52d2588
05-31 15:01:49.523  6813  6813 F DEBUG   :     x28 000000000000021c  x29 0000007ee52d1440
05-31 15:01:49.523  6813  6813 F DEBUG   :     sp  0000007ee52d1400  lr  0000007f68761cc0  pc  0000007f68761ce8
05-31 15:01:49.526  6813  6813 F DEBUG   : 
05-31 15:01:49.526  6813  6813 F DEBUG   : backtrace:
05-31 15:01:49.526  6813  6813 F DEBUG   :     #00 pc 0000000000021ce8  /system/lib64/libc.so (abort+116)
05-31 15:01:49.526  6813  6813 F DEBUG   :     #01 pc 0000000000008160  /system/lib64/vndk-sp-28/libbase.so (android::base::DefaultAborter(char const*)+12)
05-31 15:01:49.526  6813  6813 F DEBUG   :     #02 pc 0000000000008cb0  /system/lib64/vndk-sp-28/libbase.so (android::base::LogMessage::~LogMessage()+724)
05-31 15:01:49.526  6813  6813 F DEBUG   :     #03 pc 0000000000005398  /vendor/lib64/libstagefright_ccodec_utils.so (android::ConvertRGBToPlanarYUV(unsigned char*, unsigned long, unsigned long, unsigned long, C2GraphicView const&) [clone .cfi]+828)
05-31 15:01:49.526  6813  6813 F DEBUG   :     #04 pc 00000000000172c4  /vendor/lib64/libstagefright_soft_c2avcenc.so (android::C2SoftAvcEnc::setEncodeArgs(ive_video_encode_ip_t*, ive_video_encode_op_t*, C2GraphicView const*, unsigned char*, unsigned int, unsigned long)+596)
05-31 15:01:49.526  6813  6813 F DEBUG   :     #05 pc 00000000000155d8  /vendor/lib64/libstagefright_soft_c2avcenc.so (android::C2SoftAvcEnc::process(std::__1::unique_ptr<C2Work, std::__1::default_delete<C2Work>> const&, std::__1::shared_ptr<C2BlockPool> const&)+2948)
05-31 15:01:49.526  6813  6813 F DEBUG   :     #06 pc 000000000000ad90  /vendor/lib64/libstagefright_soft_c2common.so (android::SimpleC2Component::processQueue()+972)
05-31 15:01:49.526  6813  6813 F DEBUG   :     #07 pc 000000000000a7f0  /vendor/lib64/libstagefright_soft_c2common.so (_ZNSt3__114__thread_proxyINS_5tupleIJNS_10unique_ptrINS_15__thread_structENS_14default_deleteIS3_EEEEZN7android17SimpleC2Component5startEvE3$_0NS_10shared_ptrIS8_EEEEEEEPvSD_.cfi+172)
05-31 15:01:49.526  6813  6813 F DEBUG   :     #08 pc 0000000000081080  /system/lib64/libc.so (__pthread_start(void*)+36)
05-31 15:01:49.526  6813  6813 F DEBUG   :     #09 pc 0000000000023510  /system/lib64/libc.so (__start_thread+68)
--------- beginning of system
05-31 15:01:49.533  3294  3432 W NativeCrashListener: Couldn't find ProcessRecord for pid 6791
05-31 15:01:49.533  3158  3158 E /system/bin/tombstoned: Tombstone written to: /data/tombstones/tombstone_03
05-31 15:01:49.546  6800  6807 E CCodec  : Codec2 component "c2.android.avc.encoder" died.
05-31 15:01:49.546  6800  6804 E MediaCodec: Codec reported err 0xffffffe0, actionCode 0, while in state 6
05-31 15:01:49.546  6800  6800 W ScreenRecord: dequeueOutputBuffer returned INVALID_OPERATION
05-31 15:01:49.547  6800  6800 E MediaMuxer: stop() is called in invalid state 1
05-31 15:01:49.548  6800  6800 D ScreenRecord: failed
05-31 15:01:49.549  3135  3135 D EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0x733ca46320: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0x733ca2d620)
05-31 15:01:49.549  3135  3135 W libEGL  : EGLNativeWindowType 0x733ca5d010 disconnect failed
05-31 15:01:49.562  6820  6820 I media.codec: mediacodecservice starting
05-31 15:01:49.562  6820  6820 W media.codec: No seccomp policy defined for this architecture.
05-31 15:01:49.566  6820  6820 E cutils-trace: Error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
05-31 15:01:49.566  6820  6820 I C2SoftwareCodecServiceRegistrant: Codec2's IComponentStore software service created.
05-31 15:01:49.566  6820  6820 E vndksupport: Could not load libstagefrighthw.so from default namespace: dlopen failed: library "libstagefrighthw.so" not found.
05-31 15:01:49.566  6820  6820 W MediaCodecsXmlParser: unable to open media codecs configuration xml file: /data/misc/media/media_codecs_profiling_results.xml
05-31 15:01:49.566  6820  6820 W MediaCodecsXmlParser: parseTopLevelXMLFile(/data/misc/media/media_codecs_profiling_results.xml) failed
05-31 15:01:49.566  6820  6820 I ServiceManagement: Removing namespace from process name android.hardware.media.omx@1.0-service to omx@1.0-service.
```

I need screen record to run using appium which will use ADB to perform screen recording

**Update**

adb screenrecord works when using android 11/12

still need to know why it doesn't work on android 9/10

Comment: I might be lying but I believe screenrecord was disabled on emulators years ago. They might have re-enabled it recently though and the issue is completely different

Comment: @drunkencheetah adb screenrecord works on intel mac

Comment: Did you by any chance migrate from old Intel Mac to the new one using Time Machine? You can try creating a new emulator on Android 11/12 with on arm64 abi.

Comment: @drunkencheetah no, I use m1 mac from macstadium and freshly install everything, haven't tested using other than Android 9 though, will try Android 11/12

Comment: @drunkencheetah the screenrecord works on Android 11/12, updated the question

Comment: If it works with newer versions of Android but not with older versions, the chance is high that it is a bug. You should open an issue in Google Android bug tracker.